# I tried running my flutter project on my simulator but keeping get the error message on the picture

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ios-simulator, podfile

[`click to see error picture here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGGEB.jpg)I ran into below error as i tried running my flutter app on my iphone 13 Pro Max Simulator.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
```

CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing
Analyzing dependencies
Inspecting targets to integrate
Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:2:in` <top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in` <top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in` download_and_save_with_retries_async'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in` download_file'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in` initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in` new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in` source_from_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` map'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in` aggregate'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in` repo_information'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in` report'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in` handle_exception'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in` <top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in` download_typhoeus_impl_async'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in` download_file_async'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in` refresh_metadata'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in` initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in` block in source_from_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` block in aggregate_with_repos'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` aggregate_with_repos'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in` all'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in` stack'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in` report_error'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in` rescue in run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>' from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:5:in` rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in` <top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in` download_typhoeus_impl_async'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in` download_file_async'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in` refresh_metadata'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in` initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in` block in source_from_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` block in aggregate_with_repos'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` aggregate_with_repos'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in` all'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in` find_or_create_source_with_url'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in` map'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in` block in resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in` resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in` analyze'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in` install!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in` <top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in` download_typhoeus_impl_async'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in` download_file_async'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in` refresh_metadata'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in` initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in` block in source_from_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` block in aggregate_with_repos'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` aggregate_with_repos'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in` all'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in` find_or_create_source_with_url'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in` map'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in` block in resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in` resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in` analyze'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in` install!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: have you installed pods or not?

Comment: add Podfile file.

Comment: Install ruby using home-brew.  Don't rely on the pre-installed Ruby in macos

Answer (score 0):

Go to your podfile, and on second line umcomment out ios version. then try to build,

If it says that the pods our outdated,

delete the podfile and podfile.lock navigate to ios folder and run in the terminal
1.pod init
2. pod install

then pub get
build project